# How to generate url encoded anchor links with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, anchor, urlencode

```
<a href="#/search?query={{address}}" ng-repeat="address in addresses">
  {{address}}
</a>
```

generates links that are not url encoded if I understand correctly. What is the proper way to encode `#/search?query={{address}}`?

Example address is `1260 6th Ave, New York, NY`.

Answer (score 111):

You can use the native `encodeURIComponent` in javascript.
Also, you can make it into a string filter to utilize it.

Here is the example of making `escape` filter.

js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.filter('escape', function() {
  return window.encodeURIComponent;
});
```

html:

```
<a ng-href="#/search?query={{address | escape}}">
```

(updated: adapting to Karlies' answer which uses `ng-href` instead of plain `href`)

Comment: There seems to be problems with escape, encodeURI and encodeURIComponent (http://stackoverflow.com/a/12796866/377920). I wonder if Angular has some built-in encoding function we can leverage instead. Good answer otherwise.

Comment: This will return `#/search?query=undefined` if `address` is undefined. If that is not what you want see a modified solution below at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31559624/179014 .

Comment: @Tosh: isnt there any way to configure it at `$locationProvider` level ?

Answer (score 24):

@Tosh's solution will return `#/search?query=undefined` if `address` is undefined in

```
<a ng-href="#/search?query={{address | escape}}">
```

If you prefer to get an empty string instead for your query you have to extend the solution to

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.filter('escape', function() {
    return function(input) {
        if(input) {
            return window.encodeURIComponent(input); 
        }
        return "";
    }
});
```

This will return `#/search?query=` if `address` is undefined.

Comment: If input is 0, this will replace it with ""

Comment: If you want to only return an empty string for `undefined` use this - `app.filter('escape', () => (input) => input !== undefined ? window.encodeURIComponent(input) : '');`

Answer (score 15):

You could use the encodeUri filter: https://github.com/rubenv/angular-encode-uri

1. Add angular-encode-uri to your project:

   `bower install --save angular-encode-uri`
2. Add it to your HTML file:

   `<script src="bower_components/angular-encode-uri/dist/angular-encode-uri.min.js"></script>`
3. Reference it as a dependency for your app module:

   `angular.module('myApp', ['rt.encodeuri']);`
4. Use it in your views:

   `<a href="#/search?query={{address|encodeUri}}">`

Comment: I reverted this back to the original answer. It was perfectly fine and someone edited it to completely change the intent.

Comment: Why go to the lengths of importing an entire bower module when it is three lines long? A completely unnecessary dependency...

Answer (score 13):

Tosh's answer has the filter idea exactly right. I recommend do it just like that. However, if you do this, you should use **"ng-href"** rather than **"href"**, since following the "href" before the binding resolves can result in a bad link.

filter:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myapp.filters.urlEncode', [])

/*
 * Filter for encoding strings for use in URL query strings
 */
.filter('urlEncode', [function() {
  return window.encodeURIComponent;
}]);
```

view:

```
<a ng-href="#/search?query={{ address | urlEncode }}" ng-repeat="address in addresses">
  {{address}}
</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

this is a working code example:

```
app.filter('urlencode', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return window.encodeURIComponent(input);
  }
});
```

And in the template:

```
<img ng-src="/image.php?url={{item.img_url|urlencode}}"
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer with the unnecessary addition of an extra anonymous function.