# How can I invoke encodeURIComponent from angularJS template?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a block in my angular JS template a la

```
<a href="#/foos/{{foo.id}}">{{foo.name}}</a>
```

However, the foo.id property can sometimes contain funky characters ('/'). I want to do something like this:

```
<a href="#/foos/{{encodeURIComponent(foo.id)}}">{{foo.name}}</a>
```

but it doens't work? How can I fix this?

Comment: I saw this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14512986/775359 - and I was wondering - why I cannot use ```encodeURIComponent``` directly in the template... Apparently a filter is required.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could create a filter that calls `encodeURIComponent`

E.g.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.filter('encodeURIComponent', function() {
    return window.encodeURIComponent;
});
```

Then do

```
<a href="#/foos/{{foo.id | encodeURIComponent}}">{{foo.name}}</a>
```

Running example: http://jsfiddle.net/YApdK/

Comment: jimr beat me, but it's also worth noting that you should use ng-href instead of href to be sure that links are rendered by angular before they can be clicked.

Comment: This feels wrong just to use one function but it worked immediately.

Comment: Thanks, very impressive example providing javascript to html with a very short syntax

Comment: As @RickJolly pointed out, you should use `ng-href`instead of `href` to be sure that links are rendered by angular before they can be clicked. You should also probably inject `$window` into the filter instead of using `window` directly.

Answer (score 14):

*Reworked [@jimr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121006/jimr)'s code, taking into account [@aj-richardson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1299394/aj-richardson)'s recommendations.*

You can use filters within expressions to format data before rendering it.

Create a filter:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.filter('encodeURIComponent', function($window) {
    return $window.encodeURIComponent;
});
```

Then apply the filter:

```
<a ng-href="#/foos/{{foo.id | encodeURIComponent}}">{{foo.name}}</a>
```

- `ng-href` is used instead of `href` to be sure that links are rendered by AngularJS before they can be clicked.
- `$window` is injected into the filter instead of using `window` directly.

  > You should refer to global `window` through the `$window` service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing.

---

References:

1. [AngularJS API: $window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)
2. [AngularJS Developer Guide: filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)
3. [AngularJS Developer Guide: expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle malformed URI error, then you have to write a filter function and then use try-catch around the `encodeURIComponent`.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.filter('encodeURIComponent', function($window) {
    return function (path) {
        try {
            return $window.encodeURIComponent(path);
        } catch(e) {
            return path;
        }
    }
});
```