# How to encode a String in Angularjs?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I use Angularjs to send a get http request to my server. The server respond to rest request using Spring MVC. Here a snippet code on my angular url building :

```
var name="myname";
var query= "wo?d";
var url = "/search/"+query+"/"+name;
```

Here Spring MVC Controller :

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/search/{query}/{name}" , method = RequestMethod.GET , produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
@ResponseBody
public List<Data> search() {

    // search logic

return data;
}
```

I have the problem when the query contains question mark character ( ? ). The url is split so that Spring responds :
 WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my-server/web/search/wo in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc'

This is right because the question marks ? introduce the begining of request parameters. 
I've tried to use the js function `encodeURI(query)` but the question mark character is not encoded. How to encode a question mark in url ?
Thanks

Comment: You both gave the right response but stackoverflow just allow me to accept one. Thank you again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javascript has special function for this purpose [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

> encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except the following:
>   alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

while `encodeURI` also does not encode `; , / ? : @ & = + $ #` characters.

Answer (score 4):

Use `encodeURIComponent` for that.

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c1kmzwox/1/) fiddle.

```
var a = "wo?d";
alert(encodeURIComponent(a));
```

For angular specific look [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630471/how-can-i-invoke-encodeuricomponent-from-angularjs-template#16630601) answer.

still some problem then post me.