# AngularJs passing url as parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass a path url as parameter to my asp.net mvc controller method through angularjs.
When I debug I see that Path parameter on code is missing slashes in it.

Like instead of "D:\MyDir\List.txt" it show "D:MyDirList.txt"

how can I pass url as parameter in angular?

```
 public JsonResult GetData(string Path)
        {          

            var details = GetResult(Path);
            return Json(details, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

var ListPath = "D:\MyDir\List.txt";

```
$http.get("/Home/GetData",
    { params: { "Path": ListPath })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);

    });
```

Comment: I think before sending it you should encode this path using encodeURIComponent()

Comment: Please have a look at example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630471/how-can-i-invoke-encodeuricomponent-from-angularjs-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your slashes when you declare them in most languages.

`var ListPath = "D:\\MyDir\\List.txt";`

Comment: but we cannot get this \\ when we pull path from textbox. how do we handle this?

Comment: if it is passing from textbox then it is already handled correctly, just pass that variable would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

just encode your `ListPath` var like this

```
var ListPath = window.encodeURIComponent("D:\MyDir\List.txt");
```