# "/" issue in angular route

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I use ionic framework. I have an url address like below:

```
<a ng-repeat="item in list" href="#/detail/{{item.Subject}}/{{item.Id}}" class="item item-avatar">
    xxxx
</a>
```

Above code, item.Subject is a data that contains slash.(xx/xxxx). So my url becomes like :

```
<a ng-repeat="item in list" href="#/detail/xx/xxx/56" class="item item-avatar">
    xxxx
</a>
```

I try to encodeURIComponent for solving this problem. But it does not. How can I resolve this splash issiue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try this -- `/detail/{subject:.*}/:id`?

Comment: this did not work

Comment: What exact problem you are facing? Isn't it routing correctly

Comment: yes, it is not routing.

Comment: Try this!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630471/how-can-i-invoke-encodeuricomponent-from-angularjs-template