# AngularJS Filter with encodeURIComponent Not Working in Link

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, encodeuricomponent, angularjs-ng-href

I am trying to encode a value passed in an URL using a filter that calls encodeURIComponent.

My original filter

```
angular.
    module('machineorderDetail').
    filter('encodeURIComponent', function () {
        return window.encodeURIComponent;
    }).
```

was based on this post

[How can I invoke encodeURIComponent from angularJS template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630471/how-can-i-invoke-encodeuricomponent-from-angularjs-template)

When this didn't work I tried some other suggestions and injected $window, wrapped it in another function and changed href to ng-href.  Both the original version and this new version return the same output.

```
angular.
    module('machineorderDetail').
    filter('encodeURIComponent', ['$window', function ($window) {
        return function (input) {
            return encodeURIComponent(input);
        };
    }]).
```

If I do this I can see the encoded value as expected in the console out.

```
angular.
    module('machineorderDetail').
    filter('encodeURIComponent', ['$window', function ($window) {
        return function (input) {
            var retVal = encodeURIComponent(input);
            console.log(retVal);
            return retVal;
        };
  }]).
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr3Oz.png)

[image]

I can bind it like this the result is the encoded value.

```
<div>{{MachineOrderFile.DocumentName | encodeURIComponent}}</div>
```

However when I put in in either an href or an ng-href the value is not encoded.

```
<a ng-href="#!/machineorders/fileupload/{{fileProfile.DocumentName | encodeURIComponent}}/{{$ctrl.machineorder.MachineOrderHeader.ID}}">
```

The value "Japan/Singapore PO" should be Japan%2FSingapore%20PO but it is unchanged.

[screenshot of url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNcPG.png)

[image]

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

For MikeS showing encoded url when hovering in you jsfiddle
[screenshot of jsfiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dniTE.png)

Comment: When you click on the link is it not encoded? When you hover over a link as in your screenshot the browser will decode the URL. For example if you hover over the link in this example http://jsfiddle.net/oe2mbrpy/ its decoded, but clicking it shows correctly in the address bar

Comment: Correct, when I click on the link it is not encoded.  Also neither Chrome or FireFox is decoding the URL on hover.  When I hover on the link in the jsfiddle it is encoded, for what it's worth.  Added screenshot to my post to show hovering in your jsfiddle.

Comment: It looks to me as if you are using Angular and not AngularJS (an earlier version of Angular). If this is the case then filters arent available, I dont know Angular as much but its likley pipes you want to look at https://angular.io/guide/pipes