# AngularJS converting my ng-href url "slash" into "%2f"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I have an angularJS application that is a gallery. For each picture, associated with it is an `ng-href` with `#/{{files.id}}`.

`<a ng-href="#/{{files.id}}"...`

However, when I click it, the URL that is ultimately displayed is

`http://localhost:3000/gallery#%2F0`

which destroys my angular routing of

`when('/gallery/:imageID', {
      templateUrl: 'load_image.html'
    }).`

Can someone explain to me how to encode the URL's correctly? Or just use something that doesn't encode the forward slash?

Comment: Have you tried without the `#`?

Comment: In my case, I had to remove $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: @LarissaLeite Removing the html5More(true) will will write your urls with a # or #/  -  simply using / instead of #/ fixed my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate url encoded anchor links with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512583/how-to-generate-url-encoded-anchor-links-with-angularjs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL hash-bang (#!/) prefix instead of simple hash (#/)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226122/url-hash-bang-prefix-instead-of-simple-hash)

Answer (score 13):

Due to [aa077e8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8), the default hash-prefix used for $location hash-bang URLs has changed from the empty string ('') to the bang ('!').

You should try this.

**index.html**

```
<li class="active"><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('appRoutes',['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){   

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl:'app/views/pages/home.html'
        })
        .when('/about',{
            templateUrl:'app/views/pages/about.html'
        });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. The OP should have accepted this answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are two solutions:

**Not recommended: Add ! in your anchors:**

the default hash bang has been changed from "" to "!" in angular and since it will not likely change you could simply make a habit of adding "#!" in your anchor tags instead of "#".

**Recommended: Use $locationProvider:**

Use

> $location.hashPrefix("")

in your module config to use empty string as a hash bang just like old times !!

Comment: Adding `!#` is deprecated now isn't it? I just use standard html `/my-url` without any hash or bangs and it works with 1.6.4 (_html5 mode enabled_)

Answer (score 2):

Yo need not to encode anything here.
Just add * in your path Param as mentioned below and enable html5Mode

```
  app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
    .when('/base/:path*', {templateUrl: 'path.html', controller: 'pathCtrl'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
 });

 $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
```