# AngularJS: route provider changes "/" into %2F

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, routes

I am building an AngularJS appplication and I have problems with the URL when building the second view:

My appContact.js looks like this:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("appContacts", ["simpleControls", "ngRoute"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when("/", {
                controller: "contactsController",
                controllerAs: "vm",
                templateUrl: "/views/contactsView.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.when("/details/:firstName", {
                controller: "contactsDetailsController",
                controllerAs: "vm",
                templateUrl: "/views/detailsView.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/"});

            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });

        });
})();
```

In my HTML I have this link:

```
<a asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="Details" ng-href="#/details/{{contact.firstName}}" >{{ contact.firstName}}</a>
```

When I hover in the Browser I have the correct proposed link like:

```
 **http://localhost:8000/#/details/Matthew**
```

But when I click the link to navigate to the new page the URL changes to

```
 **http://localhost:8000/#%2Fdetails%2FMatthew**
```

Changing the "/" by %2 make the app fail and a blank page is shown.

Do you know why is this and how to correct this issue?

I have already read similar posts her but none of them seems to work since I have not access to the encoded URL before it reaches the Browser and the error is there.

Thanks

Rafael

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814472/angularjs-converting-my-ng-href-url-slash-into-2f?

Comment: it will work with out hash

Comment: @MMhunter: Yes I read it and I tried it in my solution but it did not work.

Comment: @tsadkanyitbarek: it does not work with or without # I have tested both solution without success

Comment: @RafaelMunoz You  can decode the parameters of URL or entire URL at back end code. using HttpUtility.UrlEncode("URL") .

Answer (score 9):

May this one will help you.

include **$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');** in your config.

```
           Example.
         <div>
            <a href ="#/table">table</a>
            <a href ="#/addPage">addForm</a>
        </div>

        app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
         $routeProvider.when("/addPage", {

                           templateUrl :"partials/add.html",
                           controller : "ngRepeatTableCtrl"

                         })
                      .when("/tablePage", {

                           templateUrl :"partials/table.html",
                           controller : "ngRepeatTableCtrl"
                     })
                      .otherwise({
                             templateUrl :"partials/table.html",
                             controller : "ngRepeatTableCtrl"

                        });


    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, working after adding locationProvider like below

```
myApp.config(["$routeProvider","$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "Templates/home.html"
        })
        .when("/class", {
            templateUrl: "Templates/class.html"
        }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/class"
    });
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

HTML

```
 <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#/home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/class">Class</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You enabled HTML5Mode, which means Angular tries to us `history.pushState` rather than using the hash to do routing. Guess your server does not support `pushState` or the option is not enabled?

Api Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have read the link and added rewriteLinks: true into the HTML5 section and it works, with an small issue:
I land in the correct URL, it shows the view correctly, but If I refresh the page it is all gone -> blank page :-(

Comment: Sounds like you need to properly configure your server. This seems not to be an issue wie Angular. Plus, "blank page" is not really a stack trace ;)

Comment: I am working locally in my computer (localhost) still in development. Anyway, thanks for the help, at least I am moving on after two days. Greetings from neighboring Karlsruhe

Comment: Well, even if your using "localhost" you have a local server that you may be able to configure! Greetings to you too :)

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same question. Removing '#' works for me. You can write like this `<a asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="Details" ng-href="/details/{{contact.firstName}}" >{{ contact.firstName}}</a>`