# my angular routes have a '#%2F' before the actual URL I have defined in the app.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am setting up my angular routes in the app.js as so:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/characters', {
        templateUrl: 'views/characters.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'characters'
      })
      .when('/framedata', {
          templateUrl: 'views/framedata.html',
          controller: 'FrameDataCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'frame'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

These URLs do work because when I type in localhost:9000/framedata or /characters it displays the view I expect. When I used the navigation bar that defines the links as expected there is a '#%2F' that is added like so: http://localhost:9000/#!/**#%2F**characters

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#/">tekkenMitzu?</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#/characters">Characters</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="#/framedata">Frame Data</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I hope this gives sufficient information, please let me know if I should give you some more information, if it is necessary I can upload this to a domain so you can see the 'live' version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below code

```
.config(function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .when('/characters', {
        templateUrl: 'views/characters.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'characters'
      })
      .when('/framedata', {
          templateUrl: 'views/framedata.html',
          controller: 'FrameDataCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'frame'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);// it will remove the #
  });
```

> And your URL having some white space if you remove the space then the `%2F` will clear

More details, please checkout it

[AngularJS converting my ng-href url "slash" into "%2f"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814472/angularjs-converting-my-ng-href-url-slash-into-2f)

Comment: if we enable html5 mode, we need to modify the server too, and also set the base tag, without those two changes the `#` won't go