# href link not working for Node Js and Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I'm new in Node JS and Angular. Making a small test project that retrieves rules data from a restful api, the api works fine... I load all rules in rules.html but each one of them has a link to view the details which is my pain right now... according to the tutorial the link should point to `/rules/details/{{rule._id}}`

#### app.js

```
var app = angular.module('SmartSoftApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){   
    $routeProvider.when('/rules/details/:id', {
        moduleId: app.id, 
        templateUrl: '/views/ruleDetails.html',
        controller: 'RulesController'
    })
})
```

The issue here is, when I click the link, I get `Cannot GET /rules/details/[id]`. I can change the link to point the html file instead but I assume that's not how it works.

I'm new at this so I appreciate if someone can guide me through this

Thanks

Comment: this question belong to `angularjs` tag, not `angular` tag, please update your post tag.

Answer (score 0):

The link should be "#/rules/details/{{rule._id}}"

```
<a href="#/rules/details/{{rule._id}}">Link</a>
```

Also as you are binding values from your model you should use `ng-href`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried that  but it does nothing... another thing, when I hover the link shown is ...localhost:3000/views/rules.html#/rules/details... is that correct?

Comment: No. The "rules.html" shouldn't be there.

Comment: Problably you are using the link in the page accessed directly by the html file. Use the route to get to the page where the link is and it will be correct.

Comment: Ohh that's a good hint, let me check that and get back to you

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814472/angularjs-converting-my-ng-href-url-slash-into-2f

Comment: thanks for that, fixed the issue with the url...but I still cannot go to the page with the link :( is there a way to debug or something? kinda frustrated here

Comment: I finally could make it work, I was missing the <ng-view>, thanks for your help @marcosspn :D

Comment: When you use the address directly on the browser does it work?

Comment: I was accessig the index page and loading the rules.html file into Iframe via javascript... so I got rid of that and added the ng-view instead. So answering your question: no it did not work 'til I added the ng-view