# Pass data with a slash in it in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When clicking on a link, I can pass data to another page:

```
<div ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:{Name: searchText}" class="slide">
    <a href="#/app/{{app.Name}}">{{app.Name}} {{app.Version}}</a>
</div>
```

When the new page comes up, I see the app's name:

[image]

This is the markup to display the name:

```
<p>{{appName}}</p>
```

However, if I want to pass the ID, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:{Name: searchText}" class="slide">
    <a href="#/app/{{app.Id}}">{{app.Name}} {{app.Version}}</a>
</div>
```

That doesn't work. When I click on the ID, nothing happens in the browser. There is no error in the F12 tools console window. And Fiddler shows no activity. I think it's because the ID has a slash in it (this is a RavenDB convention). This is what I see when I hover over the link:

[image]

Notice the last slash. I think that's messing things up.

So I tried a [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14512986/279516) to escape the slash. Now when I hover, I see this:

[image]

I thought that would have done it, but I'm back to the same behavior: nothing happens when I click on it. Nothing in Fiddler either. What am I missing? (If I change the markup to pass the Name property again, things work. So the wiring is good.)

**Edit**

I just realized that it's not that *nothing* is happening. My route provider is kicking in and taking me back to the same page that I'm already on:

```
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/apps' });
```

And this is the entire routing config:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/apps', { templateUrl: 'partials/apps.html', controller: 'appsController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/servers', { templateUrl: 'partials/servers.html', controller: 'serversController' });
    $routeProvider.when('/app/:appId?', { templateUrl: 'partials/app.html', controller: 'appController' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/apps' });
}]);
```

**Workaround**

Setting a route like this allows me to hit the right page. The only issue is that I need to prefix the number part of the ID (on the receiving page) with the literal "applications/". I guess I can do that.

```
$routeProvider.when('/app/applications/:appId?', { templateUrl: 'partials/app.html', controller: 'appController' });
```

For completeness, this is what I had to do in the receiving controller:

```
.controller('appController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {

      $scope.appId = "applications/" + $routeParams.appId;
})
```

Comment: Maybe you just need to define another route that matches the URL w/the app ID... It's hard to say unless you show us the "$routeProvider.when()" statements that you call/declare in your app ;)

Comment: I just added that to my post. I also used your workaround. If no one has an actual way to pass the entire string with the slash in it, I'd be happy to accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9hdjbp9/1/) reproduces you problem. It is a small application which has 2 routes: `/apps` and `/app/:appId`. If the `/app/:appId` route is taken, the page displays `Hello, {{appId}}`, otherwise it displays `Hello, apps`. In the startup method (`run`), I've added a hard-coded redirect to '/app/applications%2F1121' using `$location.path`. As you can see, changing the route using `$location.path('/app/applications%2F1121')` works well: the application starts and gives us the right ID: `Hello, applications/1121`. However, changing the route using a `href` doesn't work: if you click the link, the app displays `Hello, apps`, meaning the `/apps` route was taken after the `/app/applications%2F1122` url found in the link was not recognized.

Therefore, another workaround is to always use `$location.path` to change routes. Put this function in your `$routeScope` and use `ng-click` to call it ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9hdjbp9/2/)).

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.go = $location.path.bind($location);
})

<a ng-click="go('/app/applications%2F1122')" href="">
```

Escaping the slash is still required, but this workaround does not require you to change your route configuration, so it can handle any ID.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this is wired together. Why would the `run` function have a hard-coded path? And when I clicked on the `App 1122` link, I see this: `Hello, apps`. I was hoping I'd see `Hello, applications/1122`. No?

Comment: There are two fiddles in my answer. [The first one](http://jsfiddle.net/t9hdjbp9/1/) has your issue so when you click on the link, the `$routeProvider` doesn't recognize the route and redirects you to `/apps` and you `Hello, apps`. The [second one](http://jsfiddle.net/t9hdjbp9/2/) works fine so when you click the link, you will see `Hello, applications/1122`.

Comment: The hard-coded path in `run` is there just to test if changing the route with `$location.path` works or not. The fact that the page displays `Hello, applications/1121` proves that it works.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain a little bit more how the fiddle's app works.

Comment: I think I'm close. The problem is that I see `{{app.Id | escape}}` on the receiving page. I'm assuming that's because it's treated as a literal due to this HTML: `ng-click="go('/app/{{app.Id | escape}}')"`. In your example, you're using the literal ID, but I have to use a variable. Do you know how I get past this part?

Comment: That's because you pass `'/app/{{app.Id | escape}}'` as a string (see the quotes?). Try `ng-click="gotoApp(app.Id)"` and write a function `gotoApp` that takes care of the escaping and concatenating. New fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t9hdjbp9/3/).

Comment: I got it working. I had to put this in app.run: `$rootScope.gotoApp = function (appId) {
        $rootScope.go('/app/' + encodeURIComponent(appId));
    };` Thanks for the help!