# How to prevent Url encoding when passing a parameter to method in MVC controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

C# Web MVC + Angular

I have the below link on my web page:

```
<a ng-show="channel.ArtistImagepath != null" ng-href="/channel/DownloadImageFile/?filepath={{channel.ArtistImagepath}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-download" style="color: green"></i> Artist Image</a><br/>
```

When I copy the link in my browser it is:

```
//mysite/channel/DownloadImageFile/?filepath=ChannelUploads/b51535d5-4ea3-45ae-bda4-332a0ce19ee8Artist+Gomez.jpg
```

When I click on the link the filepath sent to my controller is:
ChannelUploads/b51535d5-4ea3-45ae-bda4-332a0ce19ee8ArtistDina Gomez.jpg

As you can see the + sign is replaced with a space in the filename because the URL is encoded. This results in a file not found error message..the actual filename existing on my server is: b51535d5-4ea3-45ae-bda4-332a0ce19ee8Artist+Gomez.jpg

```
public ActionResult DownloadImageFile(string filepath)
{
    filepath = "https://marvment.com/" + filepath;

    var type = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    var path = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

    path = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path);
    //path = ToUrlFriendlyString(path);

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var buffer = client.DownloadData(filepath);
        return File(buffer, type.ToString(), path);
    }
}
```

How can I prevent the file name from beign URL encoded before sending it to my controller?
I want to keep the + sign in the filename and handle the encoding in my MVC controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I prevent the file name from beign URL encoded before sending
>   it to my controller?

Actually it's the exact opposite that you need to do: *make sure* your URL parameter (the filename) is URL-encoded before being given to the browser in the first place. In this instance this should be done in Angular; see [How to generate url encoded anchor links with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512583/how-to-generate-url-encoded-anchor-links-with-angularjs)

You cannot correctly address this inside your controller action, because by the time the action gets the filename it has been automatically decoded for you.

Comment: I tried it and keep getting an error:https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=escapeFilterProvider%20%3C-%20escapeFilter