# How to eliminate spaces in URL scope variable

Tags: angularjs, scope

I want to create a URL with parameters with my Angular scope variables like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="tag in videocontent | filter:ContentFilter">
    <td><a href='/harald/?video={{tag.VideoURL}}&minute={{tag.VMinute}}&sekunde={{tag.VSecond}}' target='_blank' rel='nofollow' >{{tag.VSecond}}: </a></td>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately, the final URLs contain spaces and do not work. How can I get rid of them?

Thank you,
Benjamin

Comment: Where are the spaces coming from? You should probably be removing them in your controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate url encoded anchor links with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512583/how-to-generate-url-encoded-anchor-links-with-angularjs)

Comment: `tag.whatever = tag.whatever.replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Thank azium, problem solved with:

```
tag.whatever = tag.whatever.replace(' ', '')
```