# Escape link in data-original attribute in img tag of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, lazy-loading

I see in console that my browser is making request to a link that does not exist as I have placed it in data-original of my image. But this is a malformed URL. Sample of this is given below:

```
http://localhost:8080/%7B%7Bobject.array[0].url%7D%7D
```

I have an `<img src="" />` tag inside ng-repeat. I want my data-original attribute to be url encoded and also prevent javascript from making such calls where

```
{{object.array[0].url}}
```

is given.

Sample code is given below:

```
<div ng-repeat="object in objects">
    <img src="constant.jpg" data-original="{{object.array[0].url}}" />
</div>
```

I cannot use `ng-src` here as the link of image given in src attribute will be constant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [ngAttr](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) directive to bind your property

```
<img src="constant.jpg" ng-attr-data-original="{{object.array[0].url}}" />
```

This prevents anything seeing the attribute value before the binding happens

To escape the url you'll need something like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14512986/4910019) answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. But meanwhile I have tried using `angular.module('myApp').directive();` and this helped me a lot. I have found solution to my problem, But will mark this as an answer if it fits the query.