# Angularjs pass web adders as parameter

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to pass a web address as a parameter between views in angular but it is not working.

i am using the uiRouter and have nested states.

here is the code:

```
 .state('tab', {
url: '/tab',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})  
.state('tab.chat-detail', {
  url: '/home/:url1/:url2',
  views: {
    'tab-home': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
      controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

i am passing links in the url as:

```
 href="#/tab/home/www.somepage.com/nesteded?id=99/www.second.com/page/one/more"
```

i am sure the slashes / are causing the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `www.second.com/page/one/more` is missing a protocol. Without the protocol if you just pass that to `href` browser will interpret it as a relative url.

You either need to correct the source or parse the source to check if it has a protocol before using it in your view

Without more code provided there isn't much more help can be provided

Answer (score 0):

Use percent encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding. For a slash, you need to put %2F instead. Use a URL encoder/decoder to do it: http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Input is `http://www.somepage.com/nesteded?id=99`, so your URL encoded URL would be `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.somepage.com%2Fnesteded%3Fid%3D99`, and your link `<a href="#/tab/home/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.somepage.com%2Fnesteded%3Fid%3D99/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.second.com%2Fpage%2Fone%2Fmore">`

You can write a filter link in this stack overflow question to make it easier: [How to generate url encoded anchor links with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512583/how-to-generate-url-encoded-anchor-links-with-angularjs)