# AngularJS rel attribute binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using `ng-repeat` to create a list of videos. I need to set `rel` attribute of image in each row. I am trying in following way:

```
<li ng-repeat="video in top_videos >
    <div class=" video-list" >   
    <a href="#">   
        <img src="images/aspect-px.png" rel="{{video.video_image}}" /></a>
        <h3><a href="post.html">{{video.name}}</a></h3>                                               
    </div>   
</li>
```

It is binding the video.name in `h3` tag but not binding `rel` with `video.video_image` value. Instead of `video.video_image`'s value, it is binding it as a string i.e `http://localhost:9000/%7B%7Bvideo.video_identifier%7D%7D`. My `video.video_image` has valid image urls like `http://my-cdn-server/vaild-image.jpg`.

I have lot's of theme related jQuery methods, which need a valid `rel` value.
Please help me to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate url encoded anchor links with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512583/how-to-generate-url-encoded-anchor-links-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good read on understanding the scopes at AngularJS give it a look even if this is not the cause it will give you a great understanding on basic concepts:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

or just watch the video (3 min)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m

What I believe the issue is: top_videos is a plain variable usually this causes troubles when accessing an object inner attributes when using angular 2 way binding, the general recommendation is that there should be an additional level (topLevel.your object):

```
<li ng-repeat="video in data.top_videos >
    <div class=" video-list" >   
    <a href="#">   
        <img src="images/aspect-px.png" rel="{{video.video_image}}" /></a>
        <h3><a href="post.html">{{video.name}}</a></h3>                                               
    </div>   
</li>
```

Obviously that additional level should be added everywhere where you are using your variable