# Handling forward slashes spring mvc rest

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a rest controller setup like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"getDataFromSpaceForType/{gridName}/{spaceName}/{dataType}/{fieldNames}/{criteria}"}, method = GET, produces = "application/json")
    public EntriesForTypeName getDataFromSpaceForType(@PathVariable Map<String, String> dataRequestVariables) throws Exception {
```

The last field criteria can contain multiple forward slashes. I am unable to handle such scenario. It breaks with 404 error

Also i dont know how many slashes might come, so it becomes impossible to create multiple methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring 3 RequestMapping: Get path value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686808/spring-3-requestmapping-get-path-value)

Comment: @DanielOlszewski i took a look at it, but seems the accepted answer doesnot works with spring boot

Comment: what value do you get when using
 request.getAttribute(
        HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your URL may contain slashes, all you have to do is to encode the URL before you send/use it.

If your front-end is angularJS then you can do it like this:

[How to generate url encoded anchor links with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512583/how-to-generate-url-encoded-anchor-links-with-angularjs)

Or if you use jquery then:

[URL Encode a string in jQuery for an AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544564/url-encode-a-string-in-jquery-for-an-ajax-request)

Comment: I tried encoding the url to something like this, but it didnt work.  encodeURIComponent('/rest/query/getDataFromSpaceForType/local/privatespace/verifiedbill/feedmap/CalculatedMeasure=/bet/local/MXR/20160505/EOD_UK_IR_A2_20160505_1.txt)