# Angular2 - File download not working if the file name contains spaces

Tags: angular2-routing

Hi have a simple link that point to a file for download:

### working file link

```
<a href="/assets/test/myFile.pdf" download>This Works</a>
```

The link works but if I try to implement a download link to a file with name that contains spaces, I get a corrupted file:

## not working file link

```
<a href="/assets/test/my File not work.pdf" download>click here to download</a>
```

If I check the content of the corrupted file, I can find the html content of the homepage...

How can I manage the link to download for files that contains spaces?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate url encoded anchor links with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512583/how-to-generate-url-encoded-anchor-links-with-angularjs)

Comment: Actually no, I have already urlencoded the link and even with the %20 is now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Space characters aren't allowed in URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/is-a-url-allowed-to-contain-a-space), so you have to [encode](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) them. Have you tried to change the name of the underlying file and referencing that?

Comment: I have encoded them by creating a custom pipe, the result in the page is like this:

<a _ngcontent-c5="" download="" target="_self" href="/assets/OffertFile/2234/test%20senza%20sconto.xlsx">test</a>

The file in the folder is named "test senza sconto.xlsx", if I click on the link I get a file with the not rendered homepage html

Comment: Can you rename "test senza sconto.xlsx" to "test_senza_sconto.xlsx"? This may be the easiest solution unless there is a naming convention in place and other files are dependent on it.

Comment: Yes, using the underscore it works but the customer want to use the spaces... is it possible ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Hope you are able to find a solution.