# how can I insert single quotation in controller to filter the product names

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Good day! I would like to ask on how can I filter the product names with single quote. For example i wanted to search for the brand name " L'Oreal" it commits an error because of the single quotation. Can someone help with me with the code for it? and how can I insert it in the controller? thank you!

[image: this is my error]

**This is my code for the search in my controller**

```
$scope.filterSearch2nd = function(sid, bname, bcode, gnder, ptype, pname, size_oz, size_ml, size_g, size_pcs,scpidlist, brandnamelist, productnamelist) {


    //console.log($scope.brandnamelistvalue.length);
    brandnamelist="";

    if(bname =="" && $scope.brandnamelistvalue.length<1) {
        bname ="brandname";
    }
    else if($scope.brandnamelistvalue.length==1){

        bname=$scope.brandnamelistvalue[0];
    }
        else{
        bname="list";
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.brandnamelistvalue.length;i++){
            //console.log($scope.brandnamelistvalue[i]);
            if(i==0)
                brandnamelist+=$scope.brandnamelistvalue[i];
            else
                brandnamelist+=","+$scope.brandnamelistvalue[i];
        }

    }

    $rootScope.loader = true;
    skinCareProdService.filter2ndSearch(sid, bname, bcode, gnder, ptype, pname, size_oz, size_ml, size_g, size_pcs,scpidlist, brandnamelist, productnamelist)
        .then(function(data){
            $scope.rawSCP = data.data;
            $rootScope.loader = false;
        }
    );

}
    $("#search2nd").click(function(){


});
```

**this is my code for the search in service**

```
function filter2ndSearch(list, bname, bcode, gnder, ptype, pname, size_oz, size_ml, size_g, size_pcs,scpidlist, brandnamelist, productnamelist){
    return $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: rootURL + '/2ndlayer/search/' + list + '/' + bname + '/' + bcode + '/' + gnder + '/' + ptype + '/' + pname ,

        data: $.param({
            size_oz: size_oz,
            size_ml: size_ml,
            size_g: size_g,
            size_pcs: size_pcs,
            scpidlist: scpidlist,
            brandnamelist: brandnamelist,
            productnamelist: productnamelist
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code, what you have done? What error your are getting? Share all these details.

Comment: updated @VicJordan

Comment: Looks like you're not URL encoding the value for use in an HTTP request. Show the code for your `skinCareProdService.filter2ndSearch` method.

Comment: @phil updated already

Comment: Similar question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512583/how-to-generate-url-encoded-anchor-links-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Any string you use in an URL should be encoded correctly. You can generally use the `encodeURIComponent` function however this does not cover single-quotes which it appears you need. Try the following

```
var path = [list, bname, bcode, gnder, ptype, pname]
    .map(encodeURIComponent)
    .join('/')
    .replace(/'/g, '%27')
```

then in your `$http` call...

```
url: rootURL + '/2ndlayer/search/' + path
```

---

I highly recommend you look in to Angular's [`ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) module which supports URL path parameters and handles any encoding issues for you

Comment: ok, i'll try this, i think it is working now, i just need a little modification, thank you very much! great help

Comment: @ChristinejoyDeGuzman I just realised it wouldn't work. I've update my answer

Comment: encodeURIComponent(bname).replace( "'", "''" ) this one is also ok

Comment: @ChristinejoyDeGuzman that will only replace one `'`. If any of your strings have more than one, they will be missed